# Null SelectInput for Filtering in a Table in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dplyr, dt

I have ran into an issue, where I would like to filter a DT table using the values input from SelectInput. This works well, but the table will only appear if I have completed all values that I am filtering against.

I would like the table to appear if the values in the SelectInput are NULL, however, this does not work. I am wondering if anyone has some advice for how to show the table when SelectInput in NULL for all the categories or just for some. In other words, I would like to turn off the SelectInput filtering if nothing is selected.

An excerpt of the code that is relevant to this issue is below.

```
box(selectInput("category", "Select Category", sources_cat, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
                                      selectInput("age", "Select Age Group", sources_age, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
                                      selectInput("country", "Select Country", sources_count, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)),
                                  box(HTML("<br/> <h5><b>Topic Definitions</b></h5> <br/>")),
                                  ),
                              box(width = NULL, dataTableOutput('table'))
                      ),

server <- function(input, output){

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    cat <- input$category
    country_input <- input$country
    age_select <- input$age
    input1 <- input1
    input2 <- input2



    fsources <- sources %>% 
        filter(grepl(country_input[1], country) | grepl(country_input[2], country) | grepl(country_input[3], country) |
               grepl(country_input[4], country))

    fsources <- fsources %>% 
        filter(grepl(age_select[1], age) | grepl(age_select[2], age) | grepl(age_select[3], age))

    fsources <- fsources %>% 
        filter(grepl(cat[1], topics) | grepl(cat[2], topics) | grepl(cat[3], topics) |
                   grepl(cat[4], topics))

    #this output table only appears if there is a country and a topic selected. If not, it has an error. One must chose a country or a topic
    datatable(fsources, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
    ))


})
```

**The error message when SelectInput == NULL**

[image: The error message when SelectInput == NULL]

Comment: So this is obvious that the table will appear when you have something selected ! because the `fsources` object is depend on your input, and if the user input is empty (you set `selected = Null`), then the `fsources` object does not exist !

Answer (score 0):

Place each of your filters in an if statement, such as

```
if (all(!is.null(country_input)) {
  fsources <- sources %>% 
                filter(
                  grepl(country_input[1], country) | 
                  grepl(country_input[2], country) | 
                  grepl(country_input[3], country) |
                  grepl(country_input[4], country)
  )
}
```

That will solve the particular problem you've asked.  More generally, I'd suggest separating the derivation of the table from its presentation.  This is good programming practice because it makes your code reusable.

Also, you are more likely to get quicker and more useful replies if you provide a simple self-contained example.  Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for more information.  My code is untested because you haven't done so in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and restructure somethings, and see if I can get it to work.